# assigning a var inside AWK for use outside awk

Tags: variables, unix, awk, ksh

I am using ksh on AIX.

I have a file with multiple comma delimited fields.  The value of each field is read into a variable inside the script.

The last field in the file may contain multiple | delimited values.   I need to test each value and keep the first one that doesn't begin with R, then stop testing the values.

sample value of $principal_diagnosis0
R65.20|A41.9|G30.9|F02.80

I've tried:
`echo $principal_diagnosis0 | awk -F"|" '{for (i = 1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i !~ "R"){echo $i; primdiag = $i}}}'`
but I get this message : awk: Field $i is not correct.

My goal is to have a variable that I can use outside of the awk statement that gets assigned the first non-R code (in this case it would be A41.9).

`echo $principal_diagnosis0 | awk -F"|" '{for (i = 1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i !~ "R"){print $i}}}'`
gets me the output of :
A41.9
G30.9
F02.80

So I know it's reading the values and evaluating properly.  But I need to stop after the first match and be able to use that value outside of awk.

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `;break;` statement after `print $i`

Comment: `I have a file with multiple comma delimited fields. The value of each field is read into a variable inside the script.` sounds like a very bad starting point for whatever it is you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: `primdiag=$(echo ... | awk 'BEGIN{RS="|"}!/^R/{print; exit;}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question:

```
$ principal_diagnosis0='R65.20|A41.9|G30.9|F02.80'

$ foo=$(echo "$principal_diagnosis0" | awk -v RS='|' '/^[^R]/{sub(/\n/,""); print; exit}')

$ echo "$foo"
A41.9
```

The above will work with any awk, you can do it more briefly with GNU awk if you have it:

```
foo=$(echo "$principal_diagnosis0" | awk -v RS='[|\n]' '/^[^R]/{print; exit}')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make `FS` and `OFS` do all the hard work :

```
echo "${principal_diagnosis0}" |

mawk NF=NF FS='^(R[^|]+[|])+|[|].+$' OFS= 

A41.9
```

——————————————————————————————————————————

another slightly different variation of the same concept —  overwriting fields but leaving `OFS` as is :

```
gawk -F'^.*R[^|]+[|]|[|].+$' '$--NF=$--NF' 

A41.9
```

this works, because when you break it out :

```
gawk -F'^.*R[^|]+[|]|[|].+$' '

                       { print NF 
} $(_=--NF)=$(__=--NF) { print _, __, NF, $0 }'

3
1 2 1 A41.9
```

you'll notice you start with `NF = 3`, and the two subsequent decrements make it equivalent to `$1 = $2`,

but since final `NF` is now reduced to just 1, it would print it out correctly instead of 2 copies of it

…… which means you can also make it `$0 = $2`, as such :

```
gawk -F'^.*R[^|]+[|]|[|].+$' '$-_=$-—NF'

A41.9
```

——————————————————————————————————————————

a 3rd variation, this time using `RS` instead of `FS` :

```
mawk NR==2 RS='^.*R[^|]+[|]|[|].+$'

A41.9
```

——————————————————————————————————————————

and if you REALLY don't wanna mess with `FS/OFS/RS`, use `gsub()` instead :

```
nawk 'gsub("^.*R[^|]+[|]|[|].+$",_)'
 
A41.9
```